# using sleep() for a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I am fairly new to java, and am starting to get into using different threads in order to use `wait()` or `sleep()` on one part of my code and have the others still run.

For this project, I am using `JFrame` with the `javax.swing.*` and `java.awt.*` imports. What I am trying to do is have one of the threads (in my code it is the main, starting thread) allow the player to choose a space on the tic tac toe board, and when they click it, it will change icons, and then the AI will wait for 1 second before playing back from the second thread that I created.

Unfortunately, whenever I call `ait.sleep(1000)` (`ait` is my thread name) both threads wait for 1 second before finishing their execution. Can anyone tell me why sleeping one thread is stopping my whole execution?

Comment: Are you calling `ait.sleep(1000)` from inside the `ait` thread or from some other thread?

Comment: yes, i am calling sleep(1000) from inside ait

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why sleeping one thread is stopping my whole
>   execution

to better explain your Swing GUI is created on its own *special thread* separate from that which `main()` and other code will run in, this is done via creating your Swing components in the `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block (even if you have not done this your GUI will be run on a single thread called the [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)) . Now if you simply call `sleep` while on `Event Dispatch Thread` (or for that matter on the same `Thread`) it will wait  for the call to `Thread.sleep` to finish. Now because all Swing events are processed on EDT we pause its execution by calling `sleep(..)` thus pausing the UI events from being processed and therefore GUI is frozen (until `sleep(..)` returns).

You should not use `Thread.sleep(..)` on [`Event Dispatch Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (or any `Thread` where sleep will cuase unwanted execution blocking), as this will cause the UI to seem frozen.

[Here](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/freeze.php) is a nice example which demonstrates exactly, this unwanted behavior caused by invoking `Thread.sleep(..)` on GUI's EDT.

Rather use:

- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for example:

  ```
  int delay=1000;// wait for second

  Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new AbstractAction() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          //action that you want performed 
      }
  });
  //timer.setRepeats(false);//the timer should only go off once
  timer.start();
  ```
- [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

or if no Swing components are being created/modified:

- [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)
- [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html), you would then use `Thread.sleep(int milis)` (but thats last option in any case IMO)

**UPDATE**

`Swing Timer`/`SwingWorker` was only added in Java 1.6, however, `TimerTask` and `Thread` have been around for alot longer sine Java 1.3 and JDK 1 repsectively, thus you could even use either of the 2 above methods and wrap calls that create/manipulate Swing components in `SwingUtilities/EventQueue#invokeXX` block; thats the way things used to be done :P

Comment: thank you so much, Swing Timer worked perfectly and my program is running with far less clutter. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

[`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is a static method. Invocations of it via the reference of any given `Thread` is simply a form of convenience.

As a result, any invocation of `sleep` is really calling `sleep` on the current `Thread`, which I suspect is the Event Thread in your case.  Sleeping/blocking on the Event Thread will give the appearance of being locked up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `ait` thread to sleep, then code *that thread* to sleep. Designs where one thread "reaches into" another and pushes it around at a low level are fundamentally broken. You write the code for every thread, so write it to do what you want it to do in the first place so you'll find no need to reach into it from the outside.

Which makes more sense, for the person in the kitchen to know how to cook breakfast or the person in the bedroom to yell down and direct them to perform each step of making breakfast? Sure, you might tell them to make breakfast. But you *definitely* don't direct each step at a low level.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep` is a *static* method which causes the currently executing thread to sleep for the specified amount of time.  Java syntax allows you to call a static method via a variable, but the compiler simply uses the compile-time type of that variable to determine which method to call, i.e.

```
Thread ait = null;
ait.sleep(1000); // calls Thread.sleep(1000), causing current thread to sleep.
                 // In particular, does *not* NPE
```

You also mentioned `wait()` - while this is an instance method rather than a static it still causes the *current thread* to do the waiting (`ait.wait(1000)` would cause the current thread to wait for up to 1 second or until another thread calls `ait.notifyAll()`).

There is a `Thread.suspend()` and its counterpart `resume()` that were introduced in the very early days of Java to allow one thread to control another, but they were deprecated soon after as they are inherently deadlock-prone.  The recommended pattern if you want one thread to "control" another is to do it co-operatively, i.e. have some kind of shared flag that thread A sets and thread B reads, and have B send *itself* to sleep according to the flag:

```
volatile boolean threadBShouldRun = true;

// Thread B
while(true) {
  if(threadBShouldRun) {
    // do some stuff
  } else {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}

// Thread A
if(someCondition) {
  threadBShouldRun = false;
}
```

but it's generally easier and less error-prone to make use of the facilities that exist in the `java.util.concurrent` package.  Doing multi-threading right is much harder than it appears on the surface.

Comment: instead of `volatile` why not `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp that would be another option yes, though for booleans where one thread is only setting and another is only getting it doesn't really buy you anything over a plain volatile. It's different if you actually need the atomic `getAndSet` or `compareAndSet` operations of course.