# Animating JDialog

Tags: java, swing, animation, jdialog, event-dispatch-thread

I created a `JDialog` which I want to move and resize. My program draws `JDialog` on the screen. When the user clicks it, it should stretch to the width of the screen and then gain height. I tried it like this.

```
for(int i = 150; i <= width; i += 3) {
    dialog.setSize(i, 80);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(0, 1);
    } catch(Exception e2) {}
}

for(int i = 80; i <= 200; i++) {
    dialog.setSize(width, i);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch(Exception e3) {}
}
```

When the code is executed, it will take a while and then the JDialog will be shown stretched immediately. No expanding is shown.

Well, when the user clicks the dialog again, it will reverse the opening animation and close.

```
for(int i = 200; i >= 80; i--) {
    newMsg.setSize(width, i);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(0, 1);
    } catch(Exception e4) {}
}   

for(int i = 0; i >= -width; i -= 3) {
    newMsg.setLocation(i, 100);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(0, 1);
    } catch(Exception e5) {}
}
```

This one works correctly. The movement is able to be seen. As far as I understand, these codes are otherwise identical except they are reversed. Why doesn't the opening work as expected but the closing does?

Comment: Try using a swing Timer rather than a loop. I think the events are just getting stuck on the event queue and then all executing at once.

Comment: I'd like to see how you would do it. I commented Reimeus' message and explained...

Comment: possible duplicate of [using sleep() for a single thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074329/using-sleep-for-a-single-thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `Thread.sleep` in the `EDT`. This causes the UI to "freeze". You could use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) here instead. Here is how the initial "expand" might be handled::

```
Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    updateDialogSize();
   }
});

timer.setDelay(5); // short delay
timer.start();
```

Update dialog:

```
void updateDialogSize() {
   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   if (dialog.getWidth() < screenSize.getWidth()) { // 1st size width
      dialog.setSize(dialog.getWidth() + 5, dialog.getHeight());
   } else if (dialog.getHeight() < screenSize.getHeight()) { // then size height
     dialog.setSize(dialog.getWidth(), dialog.getHeight() + 5);
   } else {
      timer.stop(); // work done
   }

     dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myFrame);
}
```

I'll leave the dialog "contraction" as an excercise ;)

Comment: Please provide some code. I can't figure out how this should be done. I tried to do it with the Timer, but I didn't quite get it... I need multiple timers which forces me to define the ActionListener inside the Timer initialization which in turn makes me unable to stop the timer inside the ActionListener.