# How can I call JFrame with another JFrame after 2 Seconds Delay?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

```
new SplashDemoGUI().setVisible(true);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    new sample().setVisible(true);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {

}
```

Maybe someone can help me, I've put it in public domain.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074329/using-sleep-for-a-single-thread

Comment: What goes wrong? You show your code but don't tell us the problem with it.

Comment: oh sorry mr. mhouse the problem is the they show both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new sample().setVisible(true);
        }
    }, 
    2000 
);
```

This should do the job.

EDIT

> JFrame hints at Swing, so it seems Swing Timer will be appropriate. – PM 77

Comment: `JFrame` hints at `Swing`, so it seems [`Swing Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) will be appropriate.